# Jquery iteration for child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, iteration

For a simple menu I'm using jQuery to fade in a specific **h1** when a menu option is hovered. I could write the lines of code for each element, but I'd like to know how to write this more efficiently using iteration.

```
<ul class="menu_locations">
    <li><a>Option A</a></li>
    <li><a>Option B</a></li>
    <li><a>Option C</a></li>
    <li><a>Option D</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="menu_info">
    <h1>This is option A</h1>
    <h1>This is option B</h1>
    <h1>This is option C</h1>
    <h1>And finally we have D</h1>
</div>
```

This is what I thought it should look like in jQuery

```
$(".menu_locations").children().each().hover(
    function() {
        $("").fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $("").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: $(".class") returns a list of elements it's the equivalent of document.getElementsByClassName. So you can do $(".myclass li") and it will return all the li within myclass, no need for each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for `each`, jQuery iterates internally
You could use the index to target the H1 with the same index, and `stop` will stop the animation when something else is hovered.

You could also use `fadeToggle` to fade both in and out in the same handler

```js
$(".menu_locations li").hover(function() {
  $(".menu_info h1").eq( $(this).index() ).stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.menu_info h1 {display:none; position: absolute}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu_locations">
    <li><a>Option A</a></li>
    <li><a>Option B</a></li>
    <li><a>Option C</a></li>
    <li><a>Option D</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="menu_info">
    <h1>This is option A</h1>
    <h1>This is option B</h1>
    <h1>This is option C</h1>
    <h1>And finally we have D</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but like in your example, the transitions are overlapping. This creates the weird stacking effect where you briefly see two lines h1. How would i get this to go away?

Comment: Also, for some reason I cant figure out, the second info h1 line keeps replaying the hover animation(it's flickering) while moving the mouse over the element. The other menu options don't have this.

Comment: That's what happens when you fade an element out, and another one  in at the same time, and they don't have a position, they stack, one beneath the other. To fix it, they have to be positioned in the same place